# RelativeLayout displays incorrect on real device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a question regarding Android RelativeLayout. My layout works perfectly on the emulator which is configured like a LG Nexus4 (screen, resolution). But if I run the app on my real Nexus4 it has serious errors and I don't know how to fix them.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zeekedLogo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/badge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButtonPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_play"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButtonResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textButtonPlay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_resume"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabelLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zeekedLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_level"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButtonSound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zeekedLogo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_sound_on"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the screenshots of the same layout:

Emulator:

[image]

Nexus 4:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone who has an idea regarding this question?

Comment: May i ask why we can't see the resume TextView?

Comment: the textView is set to gone in Code -> txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any depency on it. Did you try changing it to invisible and see what happens? I'm just giving out random advice though since i really have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Hbibna for your advice, I checked it, but it mackes no difference :(

Comment: That's too bad. In that case i really don't know more than you do. I hope you find a solution.

Comment: Anyone else who may has an idea on that topic? regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a background color to my relativelayout it worked on my Nexus4. It's all I did ... and I think it's strange. But at the end I'm happy that it works.